# Transform Custom Task in JBPM

Tags: jbpm, redhat-bpm

I am using Business Central (JBPM) and I am trying to use the Custom Task **Transform** that transforms a Java input Object to an output Object.

As you see, I have installed the work task and the corresponding handler is in place.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the corresponding data assignments I have set the input and output objects, but when I start the process i get the following.

```
09:57:05,321 ERROR [org.jbpm.process.workitem.transform.TransformWorkItemHandler] (default task-44) Failed to find a transform
```

That means that I didn't include the related transformation methods annotated with `@Transformer`. In the handler class I see that there is the method `registerTransformer(Class<?> transformer)` that must be called in order to load the transformers.

I don't know how to invoke the previous mentioned method withing Business Central. Is there a specific menu that I should go in order to do the registration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this handler:
https://github.com/jhonfx/jbpm-examples/blob/master/krisv-jbpm/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/transform/TransformWorkItemHandler.java
It's a very old one - not maintained for 8 years. It's not part of the core jBPM repo anymore. However, if you **really** need to use it..

This is how it's used:

```
        TransformWorkItemHandler transformWorkItemHandler = new TransformWorkItemHandler();
        transformWorkItemHandler.registerTransformer(FileTransformer.class);
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Transform", transformWorkItemHandler);
```

Unfortunately, this way of calling "registerTransformer" method, can't be easily replicated in RHPAM 7 (jBPM7) where registration of handlers is done in declarative way. Therefore, I would advise to extend this handler, introduce new parameter in constructor (i.e. Class transformer) and register this transformer in the constructor (basically copy paste the code of registerTransformer inside constructor).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it worked! Although I am not using the library that you mentioned, but the [https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items), but they are almost the same.

Thanks